# Sum of MATLAB Gaussian distribution of an image is greater than 1

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using the below code to calculate the probabilities of pixel intensities for the image given below. However, the total sum of probabilities `sum(sum(probOfPixelIntensities))` is greater than 1.

[image]

I'm not sure where the mistake may be.  Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
clear all
clc
close all
I = imread('Images/cameraman.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(I);
imshow(I)
muHist = 134;
sigmaHist = 54;
Iprob = normpdf(double(I), muHist, sigmaHist);
sum(sum(Iprob))
```

Comment: Greater than 1 is how much greater? A little difference from 1 could be numerical error. Also, what is Im? (Im is a matlab function for imaginary part of a value).

Comment: Im is an image, it gives for my image sum(sum(probOfPixelIntensities)) = 514.6251

Comment: @cosmoscalibur, `Im` is not a MATLAB command. function for imaginary part is `imag`

Comment: Please post the whole with a default matlab image. Try cameraman.tif

Comment: I updated code as you please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is computing the PDF values for every pixel in the image.  `Iprob` is **not** a normal distribution but you are simply using the image pixels to sample from the distribution of a known mean and standard deviation.

Essentially, you are just performing a data transformation where the image pixel intensities get mapped to values on a normal PDF with a known mean and standard deviation.  This is **not** the same as a PDF and that's why the sum is not 1.  On top of this, the image pixel intensities don't even follow a normal distribution itself so there wouldn't be any way that the sum of the distribution is 1.

Not much more to say other than the output of `normpdf` is not what you are expecting it to be.  You should opt to read the documentation of `normpdf` more carefully: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html

---

If it is your desire to determine the actual PDF of the image, what you need to do is find the **histogram of the image**, and not do a data transformation.  You can do that with [`imhist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html).  Once you do that, assuming that encountering the intensities is equiprobable, you would **divide** each histogram entry by the total size of the image and then sum along all bins.  You should get the sum to be 1 in this case.

Just to verify, let's use the image you provided in your post.  We'll read this in from StackOverflow.  Once we do that, compute the PDF and then sum over all bins:

```
%// Load in image
im = rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XiU5.jpg'));

%// Compute PDF
h = imhist(im) / numel(im);

%// Sum over all bins
fprintf('Total sum over all bins is: %f\n', sum(h));
```

We get:

```
Total sum over all bins is: 1.000000
```

Just to be absolutely sure you understand, this is the PDF of the **image**.  What you did before was perform a data transformation where you transformed all image pixel intensities that conforms to a Gaussian distribution with a known mean and standard deviation.  This will **not** give you a sum of 1 as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that PDF is only the probability density function $p(x)$. Function which is restricted to range $[0, 1]$ is the integral over all domain of that function $\int_D p(x)dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [Matlab manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html), Y = normpdf(X,mu,sigma) computes the pdf at each of the values in X using the normal distribution with mean mu and standard deviation sigma.

The sum of the pdf is equal to 1.
The sum of the output is not.