# sum of MATLAB gaussian distribution is greater than 1

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

I want to compare the actual distribution of a time series with the normal law having same mean and std deviation. The interval on which I am computing this Gaussian distribution starts at the min and ends at the max values of the time series.

The problem is that I obtain a gaussian which has the classic bell shape but is shifted upwards, since the integral of the normal pdf is about 9.

Here it is my code:

```
N = 30; %number of segments in the interval
DISTR = struct('interval',NaN(size(shares.ret,1),N-1),'perf',NaN(size(shares.ret,1),N-1),'normal',NaN(size(shares.ret,1),N-1));

first_ret = table2array(rowfun(@(x) find(~isnan(x),1),shares.ret,'SeparateInputs',false));  %THIS LINE allows to calculate the distribution for EACH FUND on his own time horizon
for i = 1:size(shares.ret,1)

    xbins = linspace(min(shares.ret{i,first_ret(i):end},[],2),max(shares.ret{i,first_ret(i):end},[],2),N);
    y = (xbins(2)-xbins(1))/2;
    DISTR.interval(i,:) = xbins(1:end-1)+y; 
    DISTR.perf(i,:) = hist(shares.ret{i,first_ret(i):end},DISTR.interval(i,1:end))/sum(~isnan(shares.ret{i,first_ret(i):end}),2);
    DISTR.normal(i,:) = normpdf(DISTR.interval(i,:),mean(shares.ret{i,first_ret(i):end}),std(shares.ret{i,first_ret(i):end}));
end
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235717/sum-of-matlab-gaussian-distribution-of-an-image-is-greater-than-1) I found a similar question that I didn't understand how to adapt to my case.

Any suggestion/help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you remember to multiply by bin width? Also, which MATLAB version is this? You seem to be using some outdated functions (`hist`)...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dev-iL .
- Where and why should I multiply by bin width?
- I am using the latest Matlab version, but I explicitely used hist, since I couldn't  find a function that did the exact same thing. By the way the problem does not come from the ist function but rather from the normpdf one

Comment: You said in the topic, and I quote, "sum of MATLAB gaussian distribution is greater than 1" and you also mention the "integral of the normal pdf". So do you sum, do you integrate? I don't understand at what point does the result stop making sense to you. Since a probability "density" can be larger than 1 at any given point, one needs to multiply the density by the bin width to convert from density to _actual_ probability. Consider the [first and last sentences of the following wikipedia article section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Further_details)